# Pytorch BERT input gradient

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to get the input gradients from a BERT model in pytorch. How can I do that?
Suppose, y' = BertModel(x). I am trying to find $d(loss(y,y'))/dx$

Answer (score 6):

One of the problems with Bert models is that your input mostly contains token IDs rather than token embeddings, which makes getting gradient difficult since the relation between token ID and token embeddings is discontinued.
To solve this issue, you can work with token embeddings.

```py
# get your batch data: token_id, mask and labels
token_ids, mask, labels = batch
  
# get your token embeddings
token_embeds=BertModel.bert.get_input_embeddings().weight[token_ids].clone()
# track gradient of token embeddings
token_embeds.requires_grad=True
    
# get model output that contains loss value
outs = BertModel(inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,labels=labels)
loss=outs.loss
```

After getting loss value, you can use torch.autograd.grad in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73747790/14193020) or backward function

```
loss.backward()
grad=token_embeds.grad
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have already applied similar kind of thing and have resolved my issue.

Comment: Couldn't one obtain the embeddings by multiplying the embedding weight matrix with the one-hot encoded token sequence matrix? Then gradients can be back-propagated all the way to the input tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `torch.autograd.grad` ([documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html)):

```py
y_pred = BertModel(x)
out = loss_func(y_label, y_pred)  # not necessary a scalar!
grad = torch.autograd.grad(
    outputs=out,
    inputs=x,
    grad_outputs=torch.ones(out.size()).to(device), # or simply None if out is a scalar
    retain_graph=False,
    create_graph=False,
    only_inputs=True)[0]
```

You should pass `retain_graph` and `create_graph` to `True` if you want to use `grad` for computing a loss and apply backward (typically for computing a gradient penalty). Otherwise keep it to `False` to save memory and time.